# File permission automatically changed in joomla hosted by 1and1 shared host

Tags: php, joomla, shared-hosting

I manage a Joomla website hosted on 1and1 shared host. Recently, I found that an important file keeps automatically changing its permission and even if I change it back, after 15 seconds or some, it will be changed back somehow.

Does anyone know whether it's a Joomla problem or a 1and1 problem?

Note: I know there are some PHP functions that can change file permissions.

Comment: Which file is it? If it's the configuration.php file then Joomla automatically will change its permissions to 444. If it's not then can you please tell us which file is it?

Comment: @itoctopus actually there are a lot of file been changed somehow, some even just have write permission for the owner. RokCommon_Registry class in registry.php in libaries/rokcommon/RokCommon/ for example

Comment: Joomla won't change your permissions. Have you asked 1and1?  Also what is it changing them to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the Administrators' action. He want to warn me that I have to pay them.